# Nesting kivy widgets in python file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to recreate the below MDCard, I wrote in kivy language, in my python file. Although I can do it fine in kivy language I'm struggling to do it in Python.

kv file:

```py
    MDCard:
        size_hint: 1, None
        elevation: 6
        oritentation: "horizontal"
        spacing: 10
        Image:
            source: "test_image.jpeg"
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
            size_hint_x: 0.5
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            BoxLayout:
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Test"
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Test text"
            MDLabel:
                text: "Longer text here to test wrap around of MDLabel"
```

py file:

```py
    md_card = MDCard(size_hint=(1,None), elevation=6, spacing=10,
        Image(source="test_image.jpeg", allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False, size_hint_x=0.5),
        BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", BoxLayout(MDLabel(text="Test"), MDLabel(text="Test text")), 
            MDLabel(text="Longer text here to test wrap around of MDLabel")))
```

At the moment, with the py file I get a SyntaxError:

```
Image(source="test_image.jpeg", allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False, size_hint_x=0.5),
^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `add_widget` see https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/widgets.html

```
md_card = MDCard(size_hint=(1,None), elevation=6, spacing=10)
md_card.add_widget(Image(source="test_image.jpeg", allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=False, size_hint_x=0.5))
...
```